# How to filter the listview from a Edittext android?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

I have a Custom Adapter as follows.

```
public class EntryAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Item> {

    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<Item> items;
    private ArrayList<Item> fitems;
    private LayoutInflater vi;
    private contact contact;
    public EntryAdapter(Context context,ArrayList<Item> items) {
        super(context,0, items);
        this.context = context;
        this.contact=(contact) context;
        this.items = items;
        vi = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return super.getCount();
}

@Override
public Item getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return super.getItem(position);
}

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = convertView;

        final Item i = items.get(position);

        if (i != null) {
            if(i.isSection()){
                SectionItem si = (SectionItem)i;
                v = vi.inflate(R.layout.list_item_section, null);

                v.setOnClickListener(null);
                v.setOnLongClickListener(null);
                v.setLongClickable(false);

                final TextView sectionView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.list_item_section_text);
                sectionView.setText(si.getTitle());

            }else{
                EntryItem ei = (EntryItem)i;
                v = vi.inflate(R.layout.entrylist, null);
                final TextView title = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.list_item_entry_title);
                final TextView subtitle = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.list_item_entry_summary);


                if (title != null) 
                    title.setText(ei.title);
                if(subtitle != null)
                    subtitle.setText(ei.subtitle);
            }
        }
        return v;
    }



}
```

And in my activity I have added this adapter to a listview as.

```
adapter  = new EntryAdapter(contact.this,items);
                    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

I have a `EditText` and I have implemented the following logic, but I am not able to filter the data through the edittext. How Can I achieve this?

```
search.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

                    @Override
                    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                        contact.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(s.toString());

                    }
```

Comment: you can simply filter the data by default filter or need to implement filter in listview

Answer (score 0):

You are supposed to make the "EntryAdapter" implement the `[**Filterable**][1]` interface , and add your own logic:

if the entered text is not empty, create a new copy of the data , but filtered with what the user has entered.

when the filter is done, you will probably wish to call notifyDataSetChanged , and for getItem return the filtered copy instead of the original one. for getCount, return the size of the filtered copy instead of the original one. all of this should only be applied when the text is not empty. if it is, run as normal with the original data.

btw, i see you didn't implement the getCount and the getItem, so you are probably new to listView. I suggest watching the lecture "the world of listView". they also explain a bit about filtering.

Answer (score 0):

**android developer's** answerer is correct and precise. 
but here is shortcut solution, just override `toString();` of `Item` class and return field you want filter(title or subtitle or both) item class looks like.

```
public class Item {
    public String title;
    public String subtitle;
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return title;
    }

}
```

then  call `adapter.getFilter().filter(your_filter_string);` in your `onTextChanged();`

```
search.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

                    @Override
                    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                        contact.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(s.toString());

                    }
});
```

this will filter your list with respective of title.. if want filter using another field then change in toString();

Comment: can you pls elaborate it more?

Comment: whatever I type in the edittext it filters the list and show only the first name in list. even if I changed the letters then also it shows me first name only